# adding the escape char automatically

Tags: c

I am trying to define an `HTML` string as a char array, However it's really painful to add the escape chars where they are needed, meaning the I have to escape every `"` in the string and so on.

In `c#` you could do something like :

```
string x = @"\a\a\a\"; //@ adds the escape chars where needed
```

is there any way to do it? or should i add the escape chars on my own?

Comment: Do you need this for C or C++?

Comment: @RedX for c and not c++

Comment: If you have to type so much HTML or whatever into the code, why not put all of it in a separate file and compile that file into your program e.g. as `const unsigned char[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature (ala c# verbatim string literal) is available starting with C++11. You can use raw string literals like below:

```
    const char* s = R"( " " " \n \a )";     
    cout << s;
```

prints:

```
    " " " \n \a
```

a raw string starts with `R"(` and ends with `)"`

Comment: The below link discusses about Raw strings in C++11 and have got an HTML example.http://impactcore.blogspot.in/2011/03/c0x-raw-string-literals-simple-example.html

Comment: This feature is so hip it confused the syntax highlighter. Props.